# Websites with HTTP and HTTPs pages

Tags: web-application, websites

I saw a website which consists of HTTP and HTTPs parts.
that is, the website (80% of it) is over HTTP where as the Payment page is over HTTPs.

So would that website be considered as safe ?

Can it be exploited ?

From the HTTP parts of website the payment part be exploited ?

Comment: Hi. Your question is a little opened ended here I am afraid.

Comment: For example can it be exploited? In theory anything can, given a vulnerability within it and a suitable threat and threat actor to carry out the attack.

Comment: A little tip for the future: When you ask yourself "Is it safe?", you have to ask yourself "Safe from what?". You always have to add what you are trying to protect yourself from, otherwise your question is as open-ended as "Is this a good book?"

Comment: @MechMK1 okay.! will take that into consideration. thnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTP pages can be read / modified by an attacker through a [man-in-the-middle attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack).

An attacker could then easily replace any reference to the payment page (or any HTTPS page) to point to HTTP pages instead, so that he will still be able to read / modify the HTTP traffic.

Since a user is unlikely to start his session on the payment page, it will most likely start it on a unsecured HTTP page, and his whole session will be likely to be vulnerable.